# How remove striped rows in JavaFX 8 TableView

Tags: css, javafx, java-8

I´m using a default TableView in JavaFX8, but I need to remove the color of striped rows. How can I do this rewriten my css ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
.table-view {
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: -fx-control-inner-background ;
}
```

in an external CSS file.

Comment: Worked partially ... When I select first row, row´s color is blue ... When I select the second row, the color is white (and the text is white too) ... So, the line is all white. Do you have idea to correct this ?

Comment: Almost 100% ... When I select the rows, now is OK (Rows color is blue) but when I remove the focus of first line, the background color is gray ... In second line, when I remove the focus, the background color is blue.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @James_D

Comment: Works for ListViews as well, on JDK/JFX 12